# SQLite test if record exists

Tags: sqlite, validation, select, testing

I am struggling with testing if there is specific data in my SQLite database.

The method accepts a subject code, person id, and a table name. I am 100% sure those 3 things are correct.

What this should do is try to select a record. If the record can be selected return -1, otherwise return 0.

My problem is the datareader does not seem to be reading any records, when there is records in my database.

```
public int TestIfExists(string subID, string personID, string table)
{
  _sqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection(_conStr);
  bool dataRead = false;
  int rc = 0;
  try
  { 
    string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE PersonID = '" + 
                         personID + "' AND SubjectCode = '" + subID + "'";
    _sqlConnection.Open();
    SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand(selectQuery, _sqlConnection);
    IDataReader idr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    dataRead = idr.Read();
    if (dataRead == true)
    {
      rc = -1;
    }//end if   
    else
    {
      rc = 0;     
    }//end else
    idr.Close(); // Closed IDataReader
  }//end try
  catch (SQLiteException sqlEx) // Catch SQLiteException
  { 
    MessageBox.Show(sqlEx.ToString());
    throw new DataStoreError(sqlEx.Message);
  }//end catch
  catch (Exception ex)
  { 
    throw ex;
  }//end catch
  finally
  { 
    _sqlConnection.Close();
  }//end finally
  return rc; //Single return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to see if it exists or no, you can do a
`SELECT Count(*) FROM Table WHERE (...)`
and this way 0 would means doesn't exists, other wise yes.